# invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference go unit tests panic

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты, golang-gin

Есть апишка (описана ниже). Она принимает некоторый title и вызывает другую, куда передает полученное значение.

```
func (h *Handler) postEmployeeCourse(c *gin.Context) {

    token := strings.Split(c.Request.Header["Authorization"][0], " ")[1]
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading the body: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", viper.GetString("routs.LMS_s_endp"), bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    if err != nil {
        newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusUnauthorized, err.Error())
    }

    req.Header = map[string][]string{
        "Authorization": {fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", token)},
    }

    client := http.Client{}
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)

    _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading the body: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, statusResponse{"ok"})
}
```

В строке `req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", viper.GetString("routs.LMS_s_endp"), bytes.NewBuffer(body))` я обращаюсь к интерфейсу сторонней системы, который описан ниже. Т.е. реализуется некая вложенность.

```
func (h *Handler) postEmployeeCourse(c *gin.Context) {
    userId, err := getUserId(c)
    if err != nil {
        newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusInternalServerError, "user is not found")
        return
    }

    var input lms.Courses
    if err := c.BindJSON(&input); err != nil {
        newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    if err := h.services.LMSCourses.PostEmployeeCourse(userId, input); err != nil {
        newErrorResponse(c, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, statusResponse{"ok"})
}
```

Используя Postman, Swagger их взаимодействие работает нормально.

Для интерфейса `postEmployeeCourse` (описан первым) был написан тест.

```
func TestHandler_postEmployeeCourse(t *testing.T) {

    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        logrus.Fatalf("error loading env variables: %s", err.Error())
    }

    testTable := []struct {
        name                string
        inputBody           string
        headerValue         string
        headerName          string
        token               string
        expectedStatusCode  int
        expectedRequestBody string
    }{
        {
            name:                "OK",
            inputBody:           `{"title": "C#"}`,
            headerName:          "Authorization",
            headerValue:         "Bearer",
            token:               os.Getenv("token"),
            expectedStatusCode:  200,
            expectedRequestBody: `{"status": "ok"}`,
        },
    }
    for _, testCase := range testTable {
        t.Run(testCase.name, func(t *testing.T) {

            handler := NewHandler()

            r := gin.New()
            r.POST("/employee/course", handler.postEmployeeCourse)

            w := httptest.NewRecorder()
            req := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "/employee/course", bytes.NewBufferString(testCase.inputBody))
            req.Header.Set(testCase.headerName, fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", testCase.headerValue, testCase.token))

            r.ServeHTTP(w, req)

            assert.Equal(t, testCase.expectedStatusCode, w.Code)
            assert.Equal(t, testCase.expectedRequestBody, w.Body.String())
        })
    }
}
```

При запуске теста вылетает ошибка `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` на строке `_, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` первого описанного интерфейса.
Если я правильно понимаю, то обращение к интерфейсу, внутри того, для которого написан тест, не происходит. Но в Golang я совсем новичок и не все могу осознать причину того, что при обычной работе проблем нет, а в тесте тут вылетела ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

`client.Do` возвращает 2 аргумента: указатель на Response и error. вы игнорируете error, но может быть в именно в нем написано почему указатель == nil. Да, указатели могут быть nil и их надо проверять на это.

нужно проверять на ошибку обязательно и желательно на nil

```
client := http.Client{}

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // do something
}

if resp == nil {
    // do another something
}
```

p.s. скорее всего проверка на ошибку в строке err != nil  будет достаточной. если проверку прошли, то resp не будет nil-ом